# MacBook doesn't give same priority to AirPods as other devices

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, airpods

What I mean is that when I play some media on my phone, it delays for a second before it starts playing and it ensures that the audio comes out of my airpods. When I start playing media on my iPad it then does the same, pausing the media on my phone and playing on my AirPods from the iPad.

However, when I play something from my Mac it always defaults to the internal speaker and I have to manually ask it to switch to the airpods. I've checked the settings and it's supposed to switch devices automatically.

[image]

Is there a way to achieve the behavior exhibited by my phone and iPad on my Mac?